# ActiveDocument.Save NoPrompt:=True generates "Wrong number of arguments ..."

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to print a letter and its envelope to two different printers:

```vb
Sub PrintEnvelopeAndLetter()
'
' PrintEnvelopeAndLetter Macro
'
'
    Dim sCurrentPrinter As String
    Dim pageCount As Integer
    Dim currentPosition As Range
    Set currentPosition = Selection.Range 'Save the current cursor position
    pageCount = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count
    
    ' Prompt the user to ask if they are sure they are ready to print
    Result = MsgBox("Are you sure you are ready to print?" & vbCr & vbCr & "Read through your letter one last time.", _
        vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbApplicationModal + vbExclamation)
    If Result = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Display a message box asking if the user has entered the correct date
    ' at the top of their letter.
    Result = MsgBox("Did you enter the correct date at the top of your letter?", _
        vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbApplicationModal + vbExclamation)
    If Result = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Launch the Spelling and Grammar Check
    ActiveDocument.CheckSpelling
    ActiveDocument.CheckGrammar
    
    ' Save the document to the disk and do not prompt the user
    ' to save it if the user has made changes
    If ActiveDocument.Saved = False Then
        ActiveDocument.Save True
    End If
    
    ' Get the total number of pages in the document. NOTE: The
    ' envelope counts as a page
    sCurrentPrinter = ActivePrinter 'Save the current printer
    
    ActivePrinter = "HP ENVY Photo 7800 series"
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory ' move to the top of the document (envelope)
    Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintCurrentPage, Item:= _
        wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _
        wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
        PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
        PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
    ActivePrinter = "HP OfficeJet Pro 8030 series"
    For J = pageCount To 2 Step -1
        Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, J
        Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintCurrentPage, Item:= _
            wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _
            wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
            PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
            PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
    Next
    ActivePrinter = sCurrentPrinter 'Restore the original printer
    
    ' Scroll the insertion point to the very beginning of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    
    ' Save the document to the disk and do not prompt the user
    ' to save it if the user has made changes
    If ActiveDocument.Saved = False Then
        ActiveDocument.Save NoPrompt:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

It seems to be indicating that the invalid line is:

```
ActiveDocument.Save NoPrompt:=True
```

I think it is correct – see the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.save

I am using Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20188) 64-bit on Windows 10. The macro worked the day before yesterday.

I checked my printers, and both listed in the macro are installed:

[image: A screenshot of my installed Printers and Scanners]
**Figure 1.** A screenshot of my installed Printers and Scanners.

I commented out both occurrences of

```vb
' Save the document to the disk and do not prompt the user
' to save it if the user has made changes
If ActiveDocument.Saved = False Then
    ActiveDocument.Save NoPrompt:=True
End If
```

And the macro works, so I know this is the code that it is complaining about. It would seem that the compiler is complaining about a syntax error somewhere, or a function parameter that is not valid. However, every source I've consulted seems to point to this as being valid code.

Comment: I get the feeling that `NoPrompt` is only for `Documents.Save`  If you check in the Object Browser in the Word VB editor, `Document.Save` has no parameters.

Comment: @TimWilliams this is bizarre because [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.save) as I have referred to in my initial question, would seem to indicate that it does have a `NoPrompt` parameter.  What I have done right now is to remove the call entirely from the macro.  It looks as if MS needs to update the documentation.

Comment: That article is wrong I think.  It’s not unheard of